# Select an element where the attribute @id corresponds to the attribute @newid of the current node() (ONLY XPATH)

Tags: xpath, xslt

```
<content>
<root>
<parametrs @id='par1'><displayText>Text1</displayText></parametrs>
<parametrs @id='par2'><displayText>Text2</displayText></parametrs>
<parametrs @id='par3'><displayText>Text3</displayText></parametrs>
</root>
</content>

...

<paragraph @newid='par3'>Any text</paragraph>
```

I use
`ancestor::content/root/parametrs[@id = ../@newid]/displayText/`
and have no effect

BUT
`ancestor::content/root/parametrs[@id = 'par1']/displayText/` is WORK
`./@newid` is WORK

Whats's wrong?

Comment: In the context of XSLT and XPath I think you are likely looking for the `current()` function eg. `current()/@newid`.

Comment: Other options with XSLT would be to use a key.

Comment: Could you post a better example of the input? You say that `ancestor::content/root/parametrs[@id = 'par1']/displayText` works. But `content` is not an ancestor of `paragraph` so it cannot work from the context of `paragraph`. Your title speaks of  "attribute @newid of the current node"  and `paragraph` is the only element that has a `newid` attribute. So it all makes no sense when put together..

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong? Within the predicate (square brackets) the context item changes, so ".." selects from a `parametrs` element (and therefore selects nothing).

This is a join query, and joins in pure XPath 1.0 are tricky (technically, the language is not relationally complete - for that it would need range variables). There are plenty of solutions in XSLT, but it's not clear whether you want an XSLT solution (your question says "ONLY XPATH", but you've tagged it XSLT). There are also easy solutions in XPath 2.0+, but you haven't tagged the question with an XPath version, so I don't know whether an XPath 2.0+ solution would be useful to you. If you're using a framework such as Selenium that hasn't adopted newer XPath specifications then your options are very limited.

Comment: May I ask what does "easy solutions in XPath 2.0+" allude to?

Comment: In XPath 2.0, you could do for example `for $newId in ../@newid return ancestor::content/root/parametrs[@id = $newid]/displayText/` - but I'm not sure what your context item is so I don't know if this is precisely correct.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, again (someone removed my earlier comment, making me appear impolite).